# How to show array string in UILabel in UICollectionView

Tags: iphone, string, label, uicollectionview

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
  static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
UILabel *titleLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
[titleLabel setText:@"String"];
    return cell;}
```

How to show Array String in `UILabel` in `CollectionView` line which show an `Exception` is     `[titleLabel setText:@"String"];`

Comment: Exception shows         [UICollectionViewCell setText:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xc531f30
2014-10-01 15:50:32.910 MyTabBar[3626:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UICollectionViewCell setText:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xc531f30'
*** First throw call stack:

Comment: `UILabel *titleLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:100];`: `[cell viewWithTag:100];` is an `UICollectionViewCell`. Even if you cast it into a `UILabel`, it won't do.

Comment: Have you use custom UICollectionview Cell?

Comment: Then What should i do?

Comment: try [cell.contentView viewWithTag:100];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mostly its issue with tag, cause as per your crash log

`[UICollectionViewCell setText:]` means text is directly set to `UICollectionViewCell` not `titleLabel`. so you have to check proper tag value.. so ones check tag value of your label.

otherwise check that you have register your collection view cell.

Comment: i have checked your code in my app.. its working perfect if i set same tag to label. but if i have set same tag to other component then app crashes. so please check that you have set same 100 tag to other component in collection view cell or not.

Comment: my problem is remove.there is no problem in the tag value,main problem in that i impose string on cell,that's the problem.i will post the solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
   - (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:        (NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *identifier = @"Cell";
UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
UILabel *label = (UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:100];
cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor purpleColor];
label.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentCenter;[ label setText:[printArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
return cell; }
```